# Prestashop add product error: Property Product->link_rewrite is empty

Tags: xml, api, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using an ERP to perform an integration with PrestaShop, but when I sync the products it is returning an error that I can not find the problem. Did I forget some feature of the product or could it be some problem in the code? I'm using version 1.6.1.23 and my ERP is called Bling. I've tried to contact them but they told me it's something with the PrestaShop return.

XML Sent:

```
<prestashop>
<product>
    <id />
    <id_manufacturer>0</id_manufacturer>
    <id_supplier>0</id_supplier>
    <id_category_default></id_category_default>
    <new />
    <cache_default_attribute>0</cache_default_attribute>
    <id_default_combination />
    <id_tax_rules_group>1</id_tax_rules_group>
    <type>simple</type>
    <id_shop_default>1</id_shop_default>
    <reference><![CDATA[20072]]></reference>
    <supplier_reference />
    <location />
    <width>0.00</width>
    <height>0.00</height>
    <depth>0.00</depth>
    <weight>0.000000</weight>
    <quantity_discount>0</quantity_discount>
    <ean13></ean13>
    <upc></upc>
    <cache_is_pack>0</cache_is_pack>
    <pack_stock_type></pack_stock_type>
    <cache_has_attachments>0</cache_has_attachments>
    <is_virtual>0</is_virtual>
    <on_sale>0</on_sale>
    <online_only>0</online_only>
    <ecotax>0.00</ecotax>
    <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
    <price>59.90000</price>
    <wholesale_price>59.90</wholesale_price>
    <unity>PC</unity>
    <unit_price_ratio>0.00</unit_price_ratio>
    <additional_shipping_cost>0.00</additional_shipping_cost>
    <customizable>0</customizable>
    <text_fields>0</text_fields>
    <uploadable_files>0</uploadable_files>
    <active>1</active>
    <redirect_type>404</redirect_type>
    <id_product_redirected>0</id_product_redirected>
    <available_for_order>1</available_for_order>
    <available_date>0000-00-00</available_date>
    <condition>new</condition>
    <show_price>1</show_price>
    <indexed>1</indexed>
    <visibility>both</visibility>
    <state></state>
    <advanced_stock_management>0</advanced_stock_management>
    <date_add>2019-05-10 16:13:11</date_add>
    <date_upd>2019-05-10 16:13:11</date_upd>
    <meta_description>
        <language id="2"><![CDATA[]]></language>
    </meta_description>
    <meta_keywords>
        <language id="2"><![CDATA[]]></language>
    </meta_keywords>
    <meta_title>
        <language id="2"><![CDATA[]]></language>
    </meta_title>
    <link_rewrite>
        <language id="2">BLUSA_REALIST_MALH_9120072</language>
    </link_rewrite>
    <name>
        <language id="2"><![CDATA[BLUSA REALIST MALH 9120072]]></language>
    </name>
    <description>
        <language id="2"><![CDATA[]]></language>
    </description>
    <description_short>
        <language id="2"><![CDATA[]]></language>
    </description_short>
    <available_now>
        <language id="2"></language>
    </available_now>
    <available_later>
        <language id="2"></language>
    </available_later>
    <associations>
        <stock_availables>
            <stock_available>
                <id />
                <id_product_attribute />
            </stock_available>
        </stock_availables>
    </associations>
    <low_stock_alert>0</low_stock_alert>
</product>
```

Return:

Validation error: "Property Product->link_rewrite is empty"

Comment: How many languages are currently enabled on your store? Can you try to add the missing ones (ID 1?). Also you didn't use CDATA for link_rewrite, is this voluntary? At first I thought this was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982192/prestashop-add-product-error-property-product-link-rewrite-is-empty?rq=1 but your issue seems different though.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque 
When I checked I saw that I had two active languages: id1 pt-pt and id2 pt-br. I just put pt-br as default and removed pt-pt by getting only id2 pt-br. When I synchronized again he accepted and imported the products. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm glad this help! I also posted this as an answer so you can close this issue, hopefully it will help others too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by making sure you include all the translations for each activated language, example:

```
<link_rewrite>
    <language id="1">test-url-in-english</language>
    <language id="2">test-url-in-spanish</language>
</link_rewrite>
```

Alternately, you can also disable languages you are not using.

I hope this helps!